# Is there a change in the lazy identifier of the new Scala?

Tags: scala

```
def mayBeTwice(b:Boolean,i: =>Int) = {
    val j = i

    if (b) j+j else 0
}
def mayBeTwice(b:Boolean,i: =>Int) = {
    lazy val j = i

    if (b) j+j else 0
}
val x=Stream.mayBeTwice(true,{println("hi");41+1})
```

The above code execution is the same result, but this is not what is described in the functional programming in Scala book.

Comment: Could you please describe expected behaviour and what you get?

Comment: Should you send `false`, the result will no longer be same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does it differ from what you read in the book? `lazy val` delays evaluation until the first usage. Your code may look the same, but it is different. When you send false, `j` is never evaluated. This may clarify:

```
def mayBeTwice(b:Boolean, i:Int) = { 
  lazy val j = { println("hi"); i }
  if (b) j+j else 0 
}
```

From the REPL:

```
scala> mayBeTwice(true,10)
hi
res10: Int = 20
scala> mayBeTwice(false,20)
res11: Int = 0
```

In the second case, j is never evaluated.